# Why div is outside of parent div? Using React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div specified like this:

```
<button
  style={{
    padding: "0px",
    background: "yellow",
    position: "absolute",
    left: `${seat.x}%`,
    top: `${seat.y}%`,
    width: `${squareSizePercentageX}%`,
    paddingTop: `${squareSizePercentageX}%`
  }}
  key={index}
/>
```

`seat.x` and `seat.y` is always under 100. In spite of that `div` get outside of parent `div`.

This is how parent looks like:

```
<div
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    maxWidth: `calc(calc(100vmin * ${aspectRatio})+200px)`
  }}
>
  <div style={{ width: `calc(100vmin * ${aspectRatio})` }}>
    <div
      style={{ paddingTop: `${100 / aspectRatio}%`, background: "pink" }} // <-- this is here the parent
    >{listContent2}</div>
  </div>
  <div style={{ width: "200px", background: "yellow" }}>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here all the code:

```
import React from "react";
import UPUjpestRendezvenyterLayout from "../assets/UPUjpestRendezvenyterLayout.json";

class SelectSeat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const seats = UPUjpestRendezvenyterLayout.seats;
    const squareSizePercentageX =
      UPUjpestRendezvenyterLayout.squareSizePercentageX;
    const aspectRatio = UPUjpestRendezvenyterLayout.aspectRatio;
    let listContent2 = seats.map((seat, index) => {
      return (
        <button
          style={{
            padding: "0px",
            background: "yellow",
            position: "absolute",
            left: `${seat.x}%`,
            top: `${seat.y}%`,
            width: `${squareSizePercentageX}%`,
            paddingTop: `${squareSizePercentageX}%`
          }}
          key={index}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          maxWidth: `calc(calc(100vmin * ${aspectRatio})+200px)`
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ width: `calc(100vmin * ${aspectRatio})` }}>
          <div
            style={{ paddingTop: `${100 / aspectRatio}%`, background: "pink" }} // <-- this is here the parent
          >{listContent2}</div>
        </div>
        <div style={{ width: "200px", background: "yellow" }}>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SelectSeat;
```

Here an image. Small yellow rectangle should be all inside pink area.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide all the variables in the code? Does this happend for every aspectRatio you provide? It would help if you added a design of how you want it to look

Comment: Shouldn't parent be relatively positioned. So that any child inside get the positions from it.

Comment: That's a button, not a div?

Comment: If you are sure that the positions (seat.x, seat.y) are all correct based on the aspect ratio - verify that with hardcoded values or with the inspect tool of the developer tools of your browser, then it is most that you need the position: 'relative' to be added on the pink div. The "absolute" positioning needs a parent with a "relative" position - if you dont specify that on the parent you prefer it will hook to the nearest parent in the Dom tree that has position relative, the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set `position: relative` to parent `div`

Answer (score 0):

try by giving Css `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `position : relative` and don't forget to set `left` and `top` to your parent div , these changes can fix your problem